# Controller on angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, factory

On the Link below on plunker, I am trying to do a simple page connecting view 1 to view 2. 
     On view 1 we can type a text which will be shown on View2.
     My difficulty is trying to understand how I can connect the Controller1  mentioned in the $stateProviderState, to the
 Controller1.js, to the view. I find it difficult to understand how the
 factory works, how to do the injection.

### Could anyone explain to me? Thank you.

[Plnkr - Linking pages using ui-router](http://plnkr.co/edit/zdFmel?p=preview)

```
//app.module.js

var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/View1");

    $stateProvider
        .state("View1", {
            url: "/View1",
            templateUrl: "View1.html",
            view: {
              controller: 'Controller1'
            }
        })
        .state("View2", {
            url: "/View2",
            templateUrl: "View2.html",
            view: {
              controller: 'Controller2'
            }
         });
});

//Controller1.js

(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module("myApp")
    .factory('shareFactory', shareFactory)
    .controller('Controller1', Controller1);

  function Controller1(shareFactory, $scope, $http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.textView1 = "SomethingToStartWith";

    function getView1() {
      shareFactory.getData()
        .then(function(response) {
          if (response.data) {
            vm.textView1 = response.data;
            console.log(vm.textView1);
          } else {
            console.log("Something was wrong");
            return;
          }

        }, function(response) {
          console.log("Entered this Error function");
        });
    }
  }
});

//Index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.5" data-require="angularjs@1.5.5"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@<2" data-semver="1.5.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@1.0.0-alpha.5" data-semver="1.0.0-alpha.5" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.5/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="Controller1.js"></script>
    <script src="share.factory.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >

    <div class="header" ng-style="{background:'red'}">header</div>

      <div data-ui-view=""></div>

    <div class="footer" ng-style="{background:'blue'}">footer</div>
  </body>

</html>

//share.factory.js

(function() {
  angular
    .module("myApp")
    .factory('shareFactory', shareFactory);

  function shareFactory() {
    var data = '';

    return {
      getData: function() {
        return data;
      },
      setData: function(newData) {
        data = newData;
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe code explains itself?

Below code forked from your initial plunk can be found here http://plnkr.co/edit/WLe3TLTa6DKWUQ21lK3P

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when('', 'view1');

    // set up states
    // no need to specify controllers in templates
    $stateProvider
      .state('view1', {
        url: '/view1',
        templateUrl: 'view1.html',
        controller: 'Controller1',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      })
      .state('view2', {
        url: '/view2',
        templateUrl: 'view2.html',
        controller: 'Controller2',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
       });
  })

  // factory, shared data
  .factory('shareFactory', function($q) {
    var data = 'initial value';

    // mock $http using $q which returns
    // resolved/rejected promise, as would $http      
    return {
      getData: function() {
        return $q.when(data); // resolve
      },
      setData: function(val) {
        if (val.length > 0) {
          data = val;
          return $q.when(); // resolve
        } else {
          return $q.reject('value can\'t be empty'); // reject
        }
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('Controller1', function(shareFactory, $state) {
    var vm = this;

    // because async          
    shareFactory.getData()
      .then(function(data) {
        vm.data = data;
      });

    vm.set = function(data) {
      shareFactory.setData(data)
        .then(function() {
          vm.error = null;
          $state.go('view2');
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
          vm.error = e;
        });
    };
  })
  .controller('Controller2', function(shareFactory) {
    var vm = this;

    shareFactory.getData()
      .then(function(data) {
        vm.data = data;
      })
      .catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      });
  });
```

**index.html**

```
<body >
  <div data-ui-view></div>
</body>
```

**view1.html**

```
<div>
  <h1>view1</h1>
  <label>Enter a value: </label>
  <input type="text" 
         ng-model="vm.data">
  <input type="button" 
         class="btn btn-default" 
         value="Go to view2"
         ng-click="vm.set(vm.data)">
  <pre ng-bind="vm.error"></pre>
</div>
```

**view2.html**

```
<div>
  <h1>view2</h1>
  The value set in view1 is: <b ng-bind="vm.data"></b>
  <input type="button"
         class="btn btn-default"
         value="Go to view1"
         ui-sref="view1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the plunker. Injecting factory to controller, controller to main module and ui-routing

[Check this](https://plnkr.co/edit/EDVzUnRnYy0jroPvOVEv?p=preview%60)

html

```
<div class="header" ng-style="{background:'red'}">header</div>

  <div ui-view></div>

<div class="footer" ng-style="{background:'blue'}">footer</div>
```

main Js

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router','ConrollerApp']);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/View1");

$stateProvider
    .state("View1", {
        url: "/View1",
        templateUrl: "View1.html"

    })
    .state("View2", {
        url: "/View2",
        templateUrl: "View2.html"

     });
 });
```

Controller

```
var ctrl=angular.module("ConrollerApp",["Factory"])
ctrl.controller("AppController",function($scope,AppFactory){
 $scope.data=AppFactory.useData();
})
```

Factory

```
 var factoryapp=angular.module("Factory",[])
 factoryapp.factory("AppFactory",function(){

 return{
 useData:function(){
  var x=10;
 return x;
 }
}
})`
```